# Unable to typedef std::chrono::microseconds to override its definition to change its underlying type

Tags: c++, std, typedef, c++-chrono, libc++

In libc++ `std::chrono::microseconds` is defined as

```
std::chrono::duration<long long, std::micro>
```

For 64 bit platforms the long long definition is causing a number of conflicts with `int64_t`, as the code was earlier defined for the same.

In gnustl earlier `std::chrono::microseconds` was defined with `int64_t` type.

I want to override the existing definition of microseconds to the gnustl version like :

```
typedef std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 1000000>> std::chrono::microseconds;

or

#define std::chrono::microseconds std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 1000000>>;
```

How do I achieve the same. Typdef and `#define` are giving syntax errors while having `std::` and `chrono::` in the side that we desire to redefine i.e `std::chrono::microseconds`?

Comment: Can you describe the conflicts?  Someone might have a better solution than redefining a std type.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Those types are not owned by you. That is what is meant by them being in namespace `std`. It's not your code.

If you want to define your own aliases, do so in your own namespace.

Quite aside from anything else, there is probably a reason why your toolchain implements the standard library in that particular way. Even if permitted, you probably couldn't just "make it like the gnustl version" without rewriting other chunks of the standard library implementation.

If you think that libc++ has a bug on 64-bit platforms that result in `std::chrono::microseconds` failing to compile, you could raise a bug with the libc++ developers. However, you should ensure that your theory is correct first, and it is astronomically unlikely that it is. Check your other code for causes.

Comment: Thanks, yes not saying that it is a bug, I realize what you are saying, just that the above typedef is what i wanted to achieve in a few places

Comment: @AmritAyyar Your `my::microseconds` type alias will implicitly convert to `std::chrono::microseconds` everywhere you need it to.  So in the few places you need it, just use `my::microseconds`.